# Foreach not getting the right value

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The problem here return@Foreach not getting executed it always return false 
on the if statement

```
fun check() {
    var x: Int? = null
    val numbers = 1..100
    numbers.forEach {
        x = it
        if (it == 2) {
            return@forEach
        }
    }
    showingText("$x Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `it==2` condition is `true` when `it` is 2, and the statement `return@forEach` executed then. You can see it with simple logs:

```
fun check() {
    var x: Int? = null
    val numbers = 1..100
    numbers.forEach {
        println(it)
        x = it
        if (it == 2) {
            println("FINISH")
            return@forEach
        }
    }
    println("$x Hello World")
}
```

So, the `return` is executed and stops the **`forEach`** method. Then the sequence of range moves to the next item (3, 4, and so on) and action is run for it consequently.

If you want to stop actions after `2` found, use simple loop:

```
fun check2() {
    var x: Int? = null
    val numbers = 1..100
    for(it in numbers) {
        println(it)
        x = it
        if (it == 2) {
        println("FINISH")
            break
        }
    }
    println("$x Hello World")
}
```